# How do you do "git reset --hard" and "git reset --merge" in VS Codes' Git Graph?

Tags: git

I accidentally missed a line of code when I merged a branch to main.

In terminal I would use `git reset --hard` or `git reset --merge` to 'un-merge' the branch.

How would I do so graphically using the Git Graph extension to VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

In vs code, in the "Source Control" sidebar I can click on a commit and select "Reset Current Branch to Commit...":

[image]

Selecting this option brings up the "Confirm Reset" command panel:

[image]

Here I can choose to `git reset --hard`. There doesn't appear to be support for `git reset --merge`.